# Oracle, replace string for REGEXP_REPLACE based on the matched expression

Tags: regex, oracle

I want to repair some data, which was uploaded using incorrect encoding. 
Consider the following example:

```
RUE DE SAN MARTI¦O N¦ 123
```

I want to replace the `¦` with say `#`, but only in cases when it's preceeded by a number or the character `N`

My desired output is:

```
RUE DE SAN MARTI¦O N# 123
```

I tried the following replace:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('RUE DE SAN MARTI¦O N¦ 123','[\d]\¦|[N]\¦','#')
  FROM dual;
```

which correctly detects the chacter to match, but from what I know replacement string is used as literal. However I want to preserve the `N` before `¦`.
Has anyone had any luck solving similar issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
([0-9N])¦
```

and replace with `\1#`.

See  the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JUVb8q/1)

**Details**:

- `([0-9N])` - a capturing group matching a digit or `N` (can be referred to with the `\1` backreference from the replacement pattern)
- `¦` - a literal symbol is matched.

See an [Oracle online demo](http://rextester.com/NADQ60461):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('RUE DE SAN MARTI¦O N¦ 123','([0-9N])¦','\1#') AS Result FROM dual
```

[image]

Comment: Regular expressions have never been my forte, thank you very much. It worked as a charm!